# Fluent nHibernate Mapping - 1 to 0..1

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have 2 tables:

```
   TableA (Id, Name, UpdateDate)
   TableB (Id, TableAId, Amount)
```

My domain objects look like this:

```
   TableA
     public virtual Guid Id {get;set;}
     public virtual String Name {get;set;}
     public virtual TableB TableB {get; set;}

   TableB
     public virtual Guid Id {get;set;}
     public virtual decimal Amount {get;set;}
     public virtual TableA TableA {get;set;}
```

How would I map these tables so whenever I query for `TableA`, I get its reference in `TableB` if there is one?

In my TableA mapping:

```
   Component(x => x.TableB, 
             m => m.References(x => x.TableA).Column("TableAId").Nullable());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more appropiate

```
public virtual IList<TableB> TableB { get; set; }
```

Because you can have many items in TableB referencing the same item in TableA.
For the Mapping this should work:

```
public TableAMapping : ClassMap<TableA>
{
    public TableAMapping()
    {
        // other struff
        HasMany(x => x.TableB).Table("TableB").KeyColumn("TableAId");
    }
}
```

For TableB

```
public TableBMapping : ClassMap<TableB>
{
    public TableBMapping()
    {
        // other struff
        Reference(x => x.TableA)Column("TableAId");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

For 1 to 1

```
HasOne(x => x.TableB).ForeignKey("TableAId");
```

Comment: But I will never have multiple items in TableB referencing the same item in TableA. It is 1 to 1 at most, sometimes there will not be a TableB for every TableA.

Comment: As @FelipeLiberal as posted you can use `HasOne`. But I suggest that you enforce in the DB the relation 1 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fluen Mapping you can try like this:

```
public TableAMap()
{
    Table("TableA");

    Id(x=> x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
    Map(x=> x.Name).Not.Nullable();

    References(x => x.TableB, TableBId);
}

public TableBMap()
{       
    Table("TableB");

    Id(x=> x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
    Map(x=> x.Amount).Not.Nullable();

    HasMany<TableA>(x => x.TableA)
    .Nullable()
    .KeyColumn("TableAId");
}
```

If you want to ensure that it is an 1 to 1 you may use "HasOne" instead References.

Comment: Sorry I just realized I typed my TableA wrong, it does not contain a `TableBId` field. This would cause your `References` part to fail correct?

Comment: Yes, you supose to have a Column in TableA that contains the Id Value from TableB. After that you can Reference TableB.

Comment: No, I did not need to have the column in TableA that contains the Id of TableB. I was able to solve the issue, I will post the answer shortly.

Comment: I cannot create a comment on your answer :\, but it seems pretty clean. I'm glad you fiured out how to do it. I think it will be nice if you Update your question posting the Answer. Also update the title with [Resolved].

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. Using the exact schema I listed in my question, I was able to map TableA to TableB like this.

```
HasOne(x => x.TableB).PropertyRef(m => m.TableA).Cascade.All();
```